# Lazy loading, am I doing this right?

Tags: php, api, lazy-loading

I'm writing API implementation and my main API class has __call() magic method:

```
public function __call($name, $params)
{
    if (in_array($name, $this->resources))
    {
        require_once APPPATH . 'resources' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $name . '.php';

        $class_name = ucfirst($name);

        return new $class_name($params);
    }
}
```

So basically in my application if I write

```
$api->product()->get($product_id); 
// or
$api->product()->post($product);
```

resources/product.php file is included, Product object created and appropriate method called. Is this a correct way to do lazy loading and is there a better way to implement an API?

Comment: You *could* simplify it even more using PHP's native autoloading functions, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: Not only *could* you simplify this with @Pekka's suggestion, but you *should* definitely do that because a centralized autoloader is much easier to maintain.

Comment: The framework I'm using already has autoloading and I don't feel comfortable modifying it.

Comment: You can add your own autoloading function with **spl_autoload_register** without modifying the existent one.

Comment: @alessandro1997 Thanks for pointing it out, I didn't notice it at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your own autoloader afterwards. If "first" autoloader does not find file you have maybe a second logic for it or a third...
spl_autoload_register(); @http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

In that situation you dont have to care about your frameworks/applications autoloader.